# Express.js. How to generate a valid ssl certificate?

Tags: node.js, express, ssl

I have a production ready express server. And 2 webapps working with it.

The express server is in the port : 1111

I have created two letsencrypt ssl for my nginx server, and im using it with the frontend sites for app.domain.com and domain.com, it works fine.

The point is that the backend isnt reached because it must be ssl too. But... how do I setup a valid ssl for my backend? I mean I cant do it with letsencrypt because its a backend server and it doesn't have ssl.

I have tried using the same certificates that i generated for domain.com in the express server using basically this code taken from other site

```
// Dependencies
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

// Certificate
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/privkey.pem', 'utf8');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/cert.pem', 'utf8');
const ca = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/chain.pem', 'utf8');

const credentials = {
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate,
    ca: ca
};

app.use((req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello there !');
});

// Starting both http & https servers
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpServer.listen(80, () => {
    console.log('HTTP Server running on port 80');
});

httpsServer.listen(443, () => {
    console.log('HTTPS Server running on port 443');
});
```

But it worked randomly, a lot of times the request timed out because it took forever, and other times it worked, it was weird. 
But now it suddenly even stopped working, so I dont know what to do there.

What type of certificate do I have to use?

Self signed ones are rejected by chrome, and I donty know how else to generate a letsencrypt one, if the express node server is running in an ip not a domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, the problem was with my nginx virtualhosts. I created a virtualhost api.domain.com

```
    server
{
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;
    server_name api.domain.com;

    location /
    {
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:1111;
    }

}
```

And then run

```
 sudo certbot --nginx -d api.domain.com
```

Then it started to work